# Why to use “was”?

Tags: prepositions, past-tense, transitivity

**I was married to a beautiful girl.**
**I married to a beautiful girl.**

**I was connected to the internet.**
**I connected to the internet.**

Why do we use *was* in the first sentence?

Comment: You connect **to** something, but you marry someone. Hence, the second sentence in your first example should read: ***I married a beautiful girl*** (no "to").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentences in both of your examples **tell about the event/activity**. On the other hand, the second sentences tell that **you did that event/activities.**

> I was connected to the Internet - talks about *you being connected* to the Internet. 
>   I connected to the internet - talks that you, *you yourself connected* to the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

> I was married to a beautiful girl.

The girl was beautiful at some point (such as when you married her), but either you're no longer married (and she may still be, or not be, beautiful), or you're still married but she is no longer beautiful (better keep that a secret!). The point is that *was* means it happened in the past.

> I married a beautiful girl.

("to" was grammatically incorrect. It is more or less implied by "married".) "I married" took place some time in the past. Your wife may still be beautiful, or she may not be. You love her just the same, right?

> I was connected to the internet.

This has potentially two slightly different meanings. At some time in the past, you [your computer] was successfully connected to the Internet. That is, a valid connection existed. It may also be a *passive* construct: you didn't have to do much of anything, and voila, you were connected (again in the past) -- someone or something did it *to* (or *for*) you.

> I connected to the internet.

You actively did something (in the past) to connect to the Internet.